# UITableView delegate datasource not set when added from xib using custom UITableView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created an application in which I have a subclass of `UITableView` which gives me custom tableView to add as a header. Initially I am creating this header and adding it programmatically to my `UIViewController` which is working properly with expected outcome.

Now, I have added a `UITableView` to `UIViewController` from xib and changed its class to my header tableView class. When I run this I get blank tableView.

I have assigned delegate and datasource in `initWithFrame` method of header tableView class(subclass of `UITableView`)

Can anyone please help me how can I accomplish this with xib?

Comment: check it did run initWithFrame yet ? I think you load from xib file it will enter  awakeFromNib function

Answer (score 0):

set `delegate` and `datasource` from the `xib`,

1. select the `tableview` in `.xib`
2. click+drag the connections of delegate and datasource to `files owner`

.[image: click+drag the connections of delegate and datasource to <code>files owner</code>]